# No puedo eliminar el objeto seleccionado

Tags: javascript, java, netbeans, eventos, servlets

Les comento, estoy trabajando en una pagina que trae una lista de objetos desde la BD y los muestra en forma de tarjetas. A estas les agregue un boton ELIMINAR con un value="" que toma como valor el id de cada objeto y les agrego la una clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en JavaScript llamo a los objetos por clase y agrego la funcion que mande los datos al servlet para poder eliminarlos.

```
archivo javaScript
    var btnEliminar = document.getElementsByClassName("eliminarComic");
            for(btn of btnEliminar){
            btn.addEventListener('click', eliminarComic);
            var idComicEliminar = btn.value; 
            }


            function eliminarComic(){

              alert(idComicEliminar); 

                fetch( `Panel?idComic=${idComicEliminar}`, {
                                                            method: 'POST' ,

                                                            credentials: 'include'
                                                        } );




            }
```

Servlet , Cabe destacar que se agrego el id manualmente a la `funcion eliminarComic` esta elimina correctamente

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                   throws ServletException, IOException {

                               HttpSession session = request.getSession();

                                User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

                                request.setAttribute("user", user );



                            try{
                                ComicDAO comicDAO = new ComicDAO(); 
                                int idComic = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idComic"));
                                comicDAO.eliminarComic(idComic);
                            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                            out.println("Los datos recibidos no son números enteros");
                            }



               RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("PanelDeControl.jsp");
               dispatcher.forward(request, response);
           }
```

Aca va el problema, resulta que al tocar eliminar, efectivamente elimina un objeto, pero siempre elimina el ultimo objeto de la lista, independientemente de si toco el primer objeto o el segundo o el ultimo.

Efectivamente el value de cada boton esta correcto como se ve en la siguiente imagen pero al hacer click en el objeto 69 se elimino el 71...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta obtener el button seleccionado.

```
archivo javaScript
var btnEliminar = document.getElementsByClassName("eliminarComic");
        for(btn of btnEliminar){
        btn.addEventListener('click', eliminarComic);

        }


        function eliminarComic(ele){

          alert(ele.currentTarget.value); 

            fetch( `Panel?idComic=${ele.currentTarget.value}`, {
                                                        method: 'POST' ,

                                                        credentials: 'include'
                                                    } );




        }
```

Comment: Funciono excelente muchas gracias. Estaba tomando el valor pero todos me daban el ultimo por que estaba tomandolo dentro del ciclo